# visual studio doesn't tell me when i type a control that doesn't exist

Tags: visual-studio-2008, development-environment

I noticed that VS2008 doesn't tell me when I'm typing a control name that doesn't exist. why is that?

Comment: i made a mistake in the title. It was my previous question's title. what i mean, let's say, ExitButton doesn't exist. I type ExitButton.color = 'blue', visual studio doesn't underline ExitButton, telling me that it doesn't exist

Comment: what happens when you compile?

Comment: it tells me my mistake when i compile

Comment: same thing for variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you switched it off accidentally?

In the options dialog select the Text Editor node, then C# (or whatever language you are using) and go to the Advanced node.  Ensure that 'Show live semantic errors' is ticked:

[image]

More info: http://ira.me.uk/2008/09/01/switch-offon-visual-studio-2008-background-compilation/

Comment: strange... i don't have "show live semantic errors". maybe it's cause i don't have SP1? I know I have .NET framework 3.5 SP1, since it's displayed in my VS about box. but I'm not sure about my VS

Answer (score 1):

yes, the problem was that I didn't have SP1 installed

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which language you're using, but I expect the setting to be the same as it is for C#.  Go to Tools -> Options.  Then scroll the list on the left to "Text Editor".  Select the language, and look in "Advanced".  There's are options under "Editor Help" -- make sure "Underline errors in the editor" and "Show live semantic errors" are checked.